# How can I change background behind border (ListView.ItemTemplete->datatemplete) when I hover or click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem

My problem is when I click or hover in ListViewItem which also show the silver background:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNN6M.png)

this is my code xaml:

```
  <ListView 
                        Margin="0,30,0,0"
                        Height="600"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        Name="ListViewFC" ItemsSource="{Binding ListWords, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border
                                        Width="340"
                                        x:Name="Border"
                                        Height="80"
                                        Background="Pink"
                                        CornerRadius="15"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                                    >
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                x:Name="txtContent"
                                                Foreground="Black"
                                                Text="{Binding Question1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                                Margin="30 0 0 0"
                                                FontSize="15"
                                                       />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,   
                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />


                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

I want that When I hover or click It don't show the silver background.

pls, help me .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your `ListView`:

```
<ListView.Resources>
   <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
   <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" />    
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then add this outside of your `ListView` (this displays a background of gold on hover):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold" />
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: see my new comment

Answer (score 0):

The default `ControlTemplate` of the `ListView` contains a `Border` with `Padding` of 2X. Hence you have to change its template something like this

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: see my new comment

Comment: you can check it in your visual studio